# Highlight values in column 3 different colors based on values

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to highlight values in a column 3 different colors Can anyone help me figure out why im getting a next without for error.  How would you guys do this?

Thanks!

```
Sub colorcode()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Dim ront
    For ront = 13 To lastrow
        If (Cells(ront, 4).Value <= 1199) Then
            Cells(ront, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            If (Cells(ront, 4).Value >= 1200 And Cells(ront, 4).Value <= 1299) Then
                Cells(ront, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            ElseIf (Cells(ront, 4).Value >= 1300 And Cells(ront, 4).Value <= 70) Then
            Else
                Cells(ront, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            End If
    Next ront
End Sub
```

Comment: By properly indenting the code you can see that you are missing an `End If` in your code.

Comment: Indenting your code properly will do wonders to find problems like this. [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/Indentation) has a great tool to help you do this

Comment: My guess is that the second `If` should be an `ElseIf`

Comment: Looking at the subject of the post, using VBA for this result seems like too much work.  The same results can be accomplished by using conditional highlighting.  If this is really about learning VBA, that should be in the subject line.

Answer (score 0):

i'm a beginner but this code is working for me. your last condition was not correct, you cannot have a number greater than 1300 and smaller than 70 at the same time. so i changed to 7000

Also `For ront = 2 To lastrow` will leave the header untouched.

Conditions:

less or equal to 1199 - color RED

(greater and equal to 1200) **AND** (less and equal to 1299) - color YELLOW

(greater and equal to 1300) **AND** (less and equal to 7000) - color GREEN

```
Sub colorcode()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim ront
    For ront = 2 To lastrow
        If (Cells(ront, 4).Value <= 1199) Then
            Cells(ront, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If

        If (Cells(ront, 4).Value >= 1200 And Cells(ront, 4).Value <= 1299) Then
                Cells(ront, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If

        If (Cells(ront, 4).Value >= 1300 And Cells(ront, 4).Value <= 7000) Then
                Cells(ront, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
    Next ront
End Sub
```